# Map parameter to ignored property in service stack?

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, servicestack

I have a DB entity like:-

```
public class DBThing
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The Id maps to the DB primary key. I then have a service DTO like:-

```
public class Thing
{
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Identity { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The Identity field here contains a REST friendly ID like `/things/1`, made from the DB Id. I had to call it something differennt from Id, because I'm using TranslateTo and it breaks going from Thing to `DBThing` if the string `Id` is `""` and it tries to map to int Id, such as when a `POST` occurs.

The problem I have is that my route `[Route("/things/{Id}", "PUT")]` fails saying it can't find the Id property on Thing. If I remove `[IgnoreDataMember]` from the class it works fine. I can imagine why this would be (using shared code with ServiceStack serialization internally?) but I can't see how to fix this. I don't want the internal DB numeric Id serialized to the web services if at all possible.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `int? Id` which if it's null it doesn't get serialized by default in JSON / JSV Serializers.

Comment: Good solution - thanks! Although I tended to think of a nullable type property mapping to a NULL DB column, in the case of the primary key this value will legitimately be null when creating new objects to insert, so it's an exception to my normal rule and it makes sense for it to be nullable.